# Explaination about a statement in LISP about format function

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, sbcl

I have to convert a decimal number to binary in lisp. I came across this code while searching on web .

```
(defun :bits (value &optional (size 64))
(format t "~v,'~B" size value))
```

So please explain me what will each attribute of the code will do.

Comment: It's all in here ;-)   http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/a-few-format-recipes.html

Comment: I don't think that `(defun :bits ...` where `:bits` has a leading colon (and is thus a keyword) should work.  Did you remove a package prefix?  E.g., was it originally something like `(defun ex:bits ...)` ?

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor: No, this is actually defined behaviour.  Some people like to do this for little utilities they want to use everywhere (especially on the REPL).

Comment: @Svante: I've seen only LispWorks presenting a continuable error. Not sure if that can be configured away.

Comment: @Tanay I don't mind if you roll back the edit that I made,  but could you at least keep the spelling and grammar fixes?  I don't think I really changed the meaning of the question, and I hope that my edits made it easier for others to find in searches. Was there something in particular that you didn't like about it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Mongus Pong's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34413466/1281433) describes the actual behavior of the code you're looking at pretty well, but I think it's always worth mentioning *where* to find the answer, too.  The [Common Lisp HyperSpec](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw50/CLHS/Front/index.htm) is the best source of Common Lisp documentation, but there are parts of it that are a little bit hard to read.  Sometimes the documentation of directives for [**format**](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_format.htm) can be a bit dense.  In this case, you'll need to see a few sections, because some of the things in your example can apply to more than just the binary directive, ~B.

You'd want to start with [22.3 Formatted Output](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/22_c.htm), which describes the syntax of format strings:

> A directive consists of a tilde, optional prefix parameters separated
>   by commas, optional colon and at-sign modifiers, and a single
>   character indicating what kind of directive this is. There is no
>   required ordering between the at-sign and colon modifier. The case of
>   the directive character is ignored. Prefix parameters are notated as
>   signed (sign is optional) decimal numbers, or as a single-quote
>   followed by a character. For example, ~5,'0d can be used to print an
>   integer in decimal radix in five columns with leading zeros, or ~5,'*d
>   to get leading asterisks.

So we're expecting to see a tilde, then (optionally) parameters separated by colons, an (optional) at sign (@), an (optional) colon (:), and the actual prefix directive (which is case sensitive).  That means that

```
~v,'~B
```

is broken down as

```
~   ; initial tilde
v   ; prefix parameter (could also be V)
,   ; separator between prefix parameters
'~  ; prefix parameter (character following single quote)
B   ; directive (could also be b)
```

So we have two prefix parameters:  **v** and **~**, and the directive is **B**. The next paragraph in the documentation describes what **v** does when it's a prefix parameter:

> In place of a prefix parameter to a directive, V (or v) can be used.
>   In this case, format takes an argument from args as a parameter to the
>   directive. The argument should be an integer or character. If the arg
>   used by a V parameter is nil, the effect is as if the parameter had
>   been omitted.

Now, to find out what ~B does in general, you'll  need to see [22.3.2.3 Tilde B: Binary](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/22_cbc.htm), although it will pretty much redirect you elsewhere:

> This is just like ~D but prints in binary radix (radix 2) instead of
>   decimal. The full form is therefore
>   ~mincol,padchar,commachar,comma-intervalB.

That documentation describes the prefix parameters that are accepted (mincol, padchar, commachar, and comma-interval).  These are filled in from left to right.  The example **~v,'B** has two of those, so **v** is mincol and **'** is padchar.  But we still need to see [22.3.2.2 Tilde D: Decimal](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/22_cbb.htm) for what each of those mean:

> ~mincolD uses a column width of mincol; spaces are inserted on the
>   left if the number requires fewer than mincol columns for its digits
>   and sign. If the number doesn't fit in mincol columns, additional
>   columns are used as needed.
>
> ~mincol,padcharD uses padchar as the pad character instead of space.
>
> … The : modifier causes commas to be printed between groups of digits;
>   commachar may be used to change the character used as the comma.
>   comma-interval must be an integer and defaults to 3. When the :
>   modifier is given to any of these directives, the commachar is printed
>   between groups of comma-interval digits.

So, mincol, the width of the result is **v**, which means that it will be read from the list of arguments, and padchar, the padding character, is **~**.  Thus:

```
CL-USER> (bits 13 10)
~~~~~~1101                ; 10 characters wide, padded with ~

CL-USER> (bits 1022 10)
1111111110                ; 10 characters wide, no need for padding

CL-USER> (bits 1022 11)   ; 11 characters with, padded with ~
~1111111110
```

Answer (score 7):

So `(format nil "~B" 23)` will output the number in it's binary form :

```
> (format nil "~B" 23)
"10111"
```

But we want to specify the size of output string, we can do this by adding the size as a prefix in the format string.

```
> (format nil "~8B" 23)
"   10111"
```

But we don't want to pad it with spaces. We want to pad it with `~`.

```
> (format nil "~8,'~B" 23)
"~~~10111"
```

Now we don't want to hard code the size of the output in the format string, we want this passed in as a parameter. This is where ~v comes in:

```
> (format nil "~v,'~B" 8 23)
"~~~10111"
```

Now note I have been passing `nil` as the second parameter rather than `t`. Passing nil means format returns the formatted string rather than printing it. You would probably rather do this.